# Jquery delete element after prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't delete element after it was added with prepend
Edding element:

```
$('.add-btn').on("click",function(){
        tag = $('input.add-tag').val().toLowerCase();
        if (tag != '' && $.inArray(tag, tagsAr) == -1)
        {
            $('.tags-list').prepend('<li>'+tag+'<span class="del-tag"><b>X</b></span></li>');
            tagsAr.push(tag);
            $('.add-tag').val('');

        }
    });
```

Deleting element:

```
$('.del-tag').on("click", function()
{
  $($(this).parents('li').get(0)).remove();
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pembrock/uz7La/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
$(".tags-list").on("click",".del-tag",function(){
    $($(this).parents('li').get(0)).remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uz7La/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), also use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest `li` ancestor element

```
$('.tags-list').on("click", '.del-tag', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mnx6k/)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the onclick event on pageload or ready state, so click event will be binded to only those element which is already present in dom.

so for your case I have modified the code as :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tagsAr = [];
    $('.add-btn').on("click",function(){
        tag = $('input.add-tag').val().toLowerCase();
        if (tag != '' && $.inArray(tag, tagsAr) == -1)
        {
            $('.tags-list').prepend('<li>'+tag+'<span class="del-tag" onclick="deletetag(this)"><b>X</b></span></li>');
            tagsAr.push(tag);
            $('.add-tag').val('');

        }
    });
    $('.del-tag').on("click", function(){

        deletetag(this);

    });
});

function deletetag($this)
{
    $($this).closest('li').remove();
}
```

check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uz7La/4/)